# iPhone - Should I manually release my customViewController's view in its dealloc method?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using a navigation controller to push a custom viewController onto the screen. When I'm done and pop it off, I find that the dealloc method is called for the customViewController, but the "viewDidUnload" method is never called. Does this mean that the view is still there? This could be a memory problem for me if so. If this is the case, should I then release the view in my dealloc method in my customViewContoller? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessary. When your `UIViewController` subclass receives `-dealloc`, you should be releasing any retained properties. It will then get to `[super dealloc]`. Can't speak with certainty, but `-dealloc` on UIViewController should handle dumping all of it's retained properties as well. Thus your view will be released appropriately.

Not sure why `-viewDidUnload` isn't getting called, but it shouldn't matter. Perhaps if your app's memory pressure was lower when you pop the view controller, the view may get unloaded without deallocating the entire controller.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you release the view controller after you push it. For example:

```
UIViewController *myVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
[myVC release];
```

Comment: Oh yea I did that. I'm talking about the viewController's view though.

Comment: Tim, for what onnoweb wrote, everything is going to be ok. Is the dealloc method being called? Check that.